# Firebase storage download URL format

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-storage

I was wondering if there is a way to create a standard download URL for the storage items on Firebase, so I won't have to retrieve the URL first and then retrieve the image, since it is a costly operation for energy impact on iOS and Android?

so far i have noticed that the only thing that sets two URL's apart is the token from the end of the URL.

Comment: What is a standard download URL?

Comment: for example on amazon web services you can have something like : storage link / file / asset name / type ... for firebase I was thinking something like https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/appname.appspot.com/o/taVfolder%assetname?alt=media&token=someUsertoken where the usertoken would be a token generated for the user at authentication

Comment: That's what the download URLs are for: they give public read-only access to the file. One of them is automatically generated after you upload a file. If neither this nor Doug's answer solves your problem, can you share the [minimal code that is needed to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Thank you. I wound in the API Doc.  that if I use the process with SDWebImage it should load the image without having to retrieve a download URL first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you have to use the Firebase Storage API to get the download URL. It can't be derived from the path in the bucket, if that's what you were hoping.

There can actually be more than one download URL per file, they can be used independently, and you can revoke access to any one of those URLs at any time in the console.  That's what the token is for, and what makes each URL unique, and this is why you need to [use the client API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files#generate_a_download_url).

Comment: Thank you. I wound in the API Doc.  that if I use the process with SDWebImage it should load the image without having to retrieve a download URL first

Comment: I would recommend FirebaseUI's integration with SDWebImage to do this instead: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/tree/master/FirebaseStorageUI